# Why does a jQueryMobile dialog close button knock me back to my main page sometimes?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have an application with two main pages (a login page and a map page) that spawn dynamic pages to be used as dialogs, most of which have sub-pages, in a chained dialog structure.

So a perfectly normal course of action would be:

Login -> Map -> Dialog -> Sub-Dialog

Originally, I was moving from Map to Dialog using a button on the interface that looks like this:

```
<a href="#dialogID" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-rel="dialog" data-role="button" data-theme="b" class="ui-btn-right">Info</a>
```

Using that system, I can navigate perfectly fine from Login through to Sub-Dialog and back again, using either the close button on the dialog, or the back button on the browser. The address bar updates as follows:

```
Login Page: http://serverName/
Maps Page: http://serverName/#page-map
Dialog: http://serverName/#page-map&ui-state=dialog
Sub-Dialog: http://serverName/#page-map&ui-state=dialog&ui-state=dialog
```

This is perfectly normal behaviour, and works fine as long as I follow the link with the data-rel="dialog".

But I wanted to change the behaviour of my site, so that when you click on a Google Maps marker object, it opens the dialog directly. I do this with the following:

```
$.mobile.changePage($("#dialogID"), { role: "dialog" });
```

When I do this, navigating Back or hitting the Close button on the Sub-Dialog kicks me back to viewing the Login page. However, the URL is that of the Dialog state. So the URL is right, but what I see on the screen is wrong.

So instead of normally being able to go ABCD->DCBA, I'm now going ABCD->DA and skipping those two pages in the middle.

Is this a bug in jQueryMobile? Or am I using changePage wrong?

**EDIT:** Here's an in-depth JSFiddle that exhibits the behaviour: http:// jsfiddle.net/LxFJq/14/ It seems to come up because of the dynamic pages. When they were static pages ( http:// jsfiddle.net/hgb7s/2/ ) It all works like expected. The dynamic pages break the navigation, but only in the edge case of clicking from an event handler. At least I've narrowed it down.

**SOLVED:** I solved the problem myself.

The <a data-rel="dialog"> tag will automatically add a data-url attribute to the new page. The changePage() function will not. So I added them myself, and everything works. Working result, with data-rel attributes at http://jsfiddle.net/LxFJq/15/

Found this information based on the first two comments from this: https://gist.github.com/1037934

Comment: Latest development version. Using 1.2.0 RC2.
Downgraded to Stable, and it still didn't work.

Comment: Add your solution as an answer and accept it. This way others can recognize that the problem is solved more easily.

Comment: I had to wait 8 hours because I'm a new member. Fixing it now. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I was thinking - wouldn't a [popup](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-rc.2/docs/pages/popup/index.html) be more suitable for multi-level dialogs?

Comment: From the link you posted: "Note: Chaining of popups not allowed". So the easiest way right now is to chain dialogs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem myself.

The <a data-rel="dialog"> will automatically add a data-url attribute to the new page. The changePage() function will not. So I added them myself, and everything works. Working result at http://jsfiddle.net/LxFJq/15/

Found this information based on the first two comments from this: https://gist.github.com/1037934

I've submitted this as a bug to jQueryMobile's GitHub repo.
(Now I have to wait two days to accept my own answer.)